# Dynamic ArrayList object in Widget's ListView

Tags: android

I use this sample:
http://laaptu.wordpress.com/2013/07/19/android-app-widget-with-listview/

Everything is OK but I have two differences: 
I use TimerTask and dynamic ArrayList.

```
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
            int[] appWidgetIds) {    
    Timer timer = new Timer();         
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TasksView(context, appWidgetManager),100, 5000);        
    remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.appwidget);
}

private class TasksView extends TimerTask
{                
        public TasksView(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager){            
            remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.appwidget);
            thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, Widget.class);            
        }                      

        @Override
        public void run()
        {  
           // SOME operation
        }

        public void updateListView()
        {
           // HERE I need updateListView
        }
}
```

With delivery of the list of objects will not be a problem because I'll do it by batches. But how to call update again in AppWidgetProvider -> TasksView extends TimerTask

Answer (score 0):

I don't get the exact point of your question, but if you just want to refresh a listview you can use :

```
ListView.invalidateViews()
```

or use method notifyDataSetChanged of your Adapter

```
Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```